# Get Icon from Windowhandle

Tags: c#, icons

I use C# and .NET 4.0. I'm writing a program to observe the state of another program. I am already using Pinvoke with GetWindows and such to extract some basic info. This 3rd party program can open different files, and the windowicon changes accordingly. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Before you think this is a duplicate:

- I am not trying to get the icon from a .exe.
- I am not trying to get the icon of a file or folder or shortcut.
- I am trying to get the icon of a **currently open window**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the window a [`WM_GETICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message:

*"...to retrieve a handle to the large or small icon associated with a window. The system displays the large icon in the ALT+TAB dialog, and the small icon in the window caption."*

Comment: Sounds like what I need! I'll give it a try!